# Inverse set cover problem

Tags: set-theory, algorithms, approximation-algorithms

Given a universe $U$, and a set of subsets $S=\{S_i:S_i\subseteq U\}$, find $k$ such subsets so that their union size is **minimal**.

Is there a name for this problem? Is it NP? Are there efficient algorithms (possibly approximations) for it?

By set-cover, I refer to a modified version, which is the same as the above explained problem, but with the maximal union as a goal, not the "Find the least number of subsets to cover the whole $U$" problem. I am not sure if this modified version has a special name.

Note that the solution for this problem is not necessarily a complement of the set-cover solution. For example, if $S=\{\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\},\{5,6\}\}$ for $k=1$, we would choose the third subset, but for the set-cover (of size $|S|-k=2$), we would not choose the first two, but rather one of them, and the third one.

Comment: I found it on so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424155/given-n-sets-of-elements-find-minimal-union-of-m-sets

Comment: Some of your questions are answered at the stackoverflow link you posted.

Comment: I think the problem is a special case of minimizing a submodular function subject to a cardinality constraint.  That might help you look for what's known about approximation algorithms.  e.g. maybe http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5438589/ ?

Comment: $O(n^{0.25+\epsilon})$-approximation algorithm is here (and in SODA 2017): https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07866